# Android & SQLite: "Table audios has no column named downloaded"

Tags: android, exception, sqlite

I get this weird exception when i run my app on both the emulator and a USB connected device.  i can see the table inside the shell, but when I try to insert a record from the Activity acton I get this exception:

***android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table audios has no column named downloaded***

I am mostly running on an emulator with Android 1.5. The predominant part of my code is linked to this tutorial - http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/1954.

This is the create statement I use:

```
 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
  "create table audios ( _id integer primary key autoincrement, "
  + "user_name text not null, title text not null, file_path text not null, download integer not null, " 
  + "created_at integer not null, downloaded_at integer not null );";
```

This is the insert code I use:

```
//--- insert a title into the database ---
 public long insertTitle(String user_name, String title, String file_path, Integer downloaded, long created_at, String downloaded_at ) {
  ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
  initialValues.put(KEY_USER_NAME, user_name);
  initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
  initialValues.put(KEY_FILE, file_path);
  initialValues.put(KEY_DOWNLOADED, downloaded);
  initialValues.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at);
  initialValues.put(KEY_DOWNLOADED_AT, downloaded_at);
  return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
 }
```

Comment: Please don't delete questions on StackOverflow unless they are wrong or similar. It was a perfectly valid question. However, if you still want it deleted, and don't have the delete action yourself (I don't know at what rep it appears if you don't have it for your own questions from the beginning), please leave another comment here and someone can probably do it for you.

Comment: Yeah it was a complete mistake and it should stay. When you posted your answer I got it from another place, and felt duh and didn't want people to spend time on it. Silly move of me. :-( It should stay as a monument of one of those days where you don't see the trees cause of the forest. :-)

Comment: Also, the next time someone else has a similar error message and googles for it, they'll find your question, the answers posted here, and will slap their forehead just as you did. So even if the answer did not help you, since you found it yourself before I posted one here, it might benefit someone else that has been staring holes in their screen for too long on a similar one. I've had them myself, you look at a code you just *know* is right, but still gives an error, until someone points out "uhm, why are you using the wrong variable here?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will hazard a guess that you have this in your code:

```
public static final String KEY_DOWNLOADED = "downloaded";
```

The reason for the error message is that...

> table audios has no column named downloaded

Really. It doesn't, just as the error message says.

If you re-read your table-creation SQL, you'll notice that the column name is actually `download`, not `download`**ed**.

So correct your code to use the correct column name and you should be set. Note that correcting the code could mean either:

1. changing the column name in your table to be `downloaded` instead of just `download`. Personally I would go with this one, unless you have lots of other code already using `download`, since `download` in my mind is either `a download` or `to download`, not `has been downloaded`, but it really depends on its actual meaning
2. changing the column name in the SQL that accesses the table to use the same column name as the table

Comment: Was about to post this. Good catch Lasse.

Comment: Yeah and I am an idiot. I will go and hide somewhere now in shame. :-)

Comment: .... and I missed the answer and deleted the question. :-( Now I am a two-folded idiot. :-)

Comment: I rolled it back, if you still want it deleted, post a comment below mine on your question. However, it was a perfectly valid question, even though it was also a lesson in humility :) Also, you should accept my answer (or ideally wait a bit to see if someone else posts a better one and accept theirs) if you feel it answered your question (or put you on the right track). This gives back to the community and in time will benefit you as well.

Answer (score 0):

if you create the table without this column for before ,and then you add this column, just modify the database version ,the eclipse will delete the old database and create the new database .

Answer (score 0):

My case is a little different but the error message is the same. "Table xxx hax no column named yyy". I'm answering here so if someone is also "staring holes in the screeen" may find a tip.
If you define your table with placeholders like this:

```
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_VISITA = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, %s %s, %s %s, %s %s, %s %s, %s %s, %s %s)", 
        TableVisit.NAME,
        TableVisit.COL_NR_VISITA,
        TableVisit.COL_TP_CASA,
        FIELD_TEXT,
        TableVisit.COL_NR_CASA, 
        FIELD_INTEGER,
        TableVisit.COL_BENS_MOVEIS,
        FIELD_INTEGER,
        TableVisit.COL_DT_VISITA,
        FIELD_TEXT,
        TableVisit.COL_NR_COMODOS,
        FIELD_INTEGER,
        TableVisit.COL_NR_ISENCAO,
        FIELD_INTEGER,
        TableVisit.COL_NR_QUARTOS,
        FIELD_INTEGER
        );
```

always count your placeholders carefully. If you miss 2, like in this example code, when adding another field, table may be created giving the message error mentioned only when you try do insert a new record to the table.
(my first answer here, so any comment is more than welcome.)